# Подскажите библиотеку для парсинга excel файлов на чистом си

Tags: c, excel

Подскажите библиотеку для парсинга excel файлов на чистом си. Не могу найти адекватный вариант

Comment: Не хочу пугать автора вопроса, но, по моему, это настолько разные вселенные, что такой библиотеки может просто не быть на всём белом свете...

Answer (score 4):

Пожалуй, работа с Excel в один шаг, на чистом Си, никого не заинтересовала настолько, чтобы сделать полноценные байндинги. [Есть проект libexcel](https://github.com/devinsmith/libexcel) десятилетней давности, но насколько эта библиотека умеет читать-писать современный формат файлов - ХЗ

Но тем не менее, это вполне возможно сделать в два шага.

1. [Excel предоставляет](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/excel-object-model-overview) полный набор COM интерфейсов
2. С любым COM интерфейсом можно [работать через чистый Си.](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13601/COM-in-plain-C)

На сайте Майкрософт есть [пример работы с COM интерфейсом Excel](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/automate-excel-from-c) на якобы С++. От С++ там только `new` и `delete`, в остальном же чистый Си.

Но я вам сразу скажу: работа с COM через Си - это танец с саблями по граблям. Поэтому...

Удачи!!

Да, кстати. Вам это нужно для Windows или Linux?

Comment: ... это танец с саблями на поверхности включенной циркулярной пилы...

Answer (score 2):

Я задам Вам ответный вопрос - а зачем Вам библиотека для такой сложной штуки на чистом c?

Дело в том, что, скорее всего, такой библиотеки не существует.

Потому что это очень специфичная задача: вряд ли людям, которым **нужно** парсить Excel, **требуется**, чтобы библиотека была на чистом C.

я могу предположить, что есть библиотеки на C++. Есть множество библиотек на C#. Так, может, проще написать обертку, которая позволит из С вызывать библиотеку на другом языке?